# Raspberry Pie Files Not syncing,?

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi3

[image]

I am sshing into my raspberry pi. In Winscp its showing the file i want to run in my pi. but when i nano into the same file in putty, its a completely different file.

Not sure why its doing this as i have used ssh on other things like servers and the file system updates in real time.

I'm confused and need some help.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to copy your file manually with a scp command? You can use crontab to run a task automatically and maintain your file up to date.

Comment: Do you think it could be a bad sd card?

Comment: No. I have worked with the ftp and the raspberry before and I had to make the synchronization manually. Try using a scp command to copy your file since your pc to the raspberry. scp your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /some/local/directory

Comment: If it command works, you can leave a crontab that make it each minute for example